# Two solutions sharing one project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Is this doable? if yes? what are some of the things I should be concerned with?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

No concerns. We do it all the time.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's doable.

Just be careful if you're using a version control system. If you are, they control locking at the file system level and that may cause some clashing.